# How to rescale a cosine function and superimpose it on another plot?

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time series plot - the x-axis is Date (Jan 2005-April 2022), and the y-axis is Rate (-100%-100%). There are already two lines in this plot. I would like to plot a cosine function with a cycle (2pi) of 40 months on this same plot. How could I achieve this?

I tried the following code right after I plotted the other two lines. But it doesn't work.

```
x = np.arange(0,208/40*2*np.pi,0.1)
cos_40 = np.cos(x)
%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline
plt.plot(cos_40)
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: Where does the cos_35 come from?

Comment: sorry, it's supposed to be cos_40. Edited!